# Assign vector in indexing another vector

Tags: r, variable-assignment

Here's a little code to illustrate my problem:

```
x <- 1:10
# > x 
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

y <- rep(letters[1:2], 5)
# > y 
#  [1] "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b"

z <- rep(c(5,4), 5)
# > z
#  [1] 5 4 5 4 5 4 5 4 5 4
```

Now, depending in which order I issue the next two commands I get different subassignments:

- `x` first, `y` second:

  ```
  x[(x == 2) & (y != "a") & (z == 4)] <- "a"
  # > x
  #  [1] "1"  "a"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"

  y[(x == 2) & (y != "a") & (z == 4)] <- "a"
  # > y
  #  [1] "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b"
  ```
- `y` first, `x` second:

  ```
    y[(x == 2) & (y != "a") & (z == 4)] <- "a" 
    # > y
    #  [1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b"

    x[(x == 2) & (y != "a") & (z == 4)] <- "a"
    # > x
    #  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
  ```

The assignment of the second vector depends on the assignment done in the previous vector. Hence, in the second assignment I need to make sure that I have the relevant indices still available for the second assigment. My first idea is:

```
x[ind <- ((x == 2) & (y != "a") & (z == 4))] <- "a"
y[ind] <- "a"
rm(ind)
```

I want to avoid a separate call to do the assignment of the `ind` vector given that I might be doing a lot of this. Would that still be considered good coding in `R` or can it lead to any devious behaviour I haven't thought of?

Comment: If the element indices of `x` and `y` you want to change are the same, your idea works. Furthermore, you avoid duplicate calculations (you are calling twice `(x == 2) & (y != "a") & (z == 4)`). Doing step by step, you are changing `x` before `y` and this may affect the calculation of the elements of `y` you want to change.

Comment: In your case I would try to create 2 different vectors like xx and yy and do oparations on them like: ``yy[(x == 2) & (y != "a") & (z == 4)] <- "a" ``, so you won't change the conditions

Comment: I just updated the question to stress that I want to have the indices available and that I want to do this in a clear manner but at the same time avoid a separate call to do the assignment of the `ind` vector. Would that still be considered good coding in `R`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution seems fine. However, I would still regard your code as somewhat bad practice. Consider your first bullet:

```
x[(x == 2) & (y != "a") & (z == 4)] <- "a"
y[(x == 2) & (y != "a") & (z == 4)] <- "a"
```

At line 1, your `numeric` variable `x` is converted to a `character` since you assign `"a"` to the `TRUE` indices or maybe not if no indices are `TRUE`. Hence your output type is not really clear. That's somewhat bad practice and can lead to all sorts or problems downstream. You should stay within on type.

This also means that the `x == 2` in your second line in the above is somewhat unclear though R correctly interprets the comparison. Again however, it could cause problems in a more elaborate example. But maybe you don't have these type issues in your application.

Comment: I should use `identical()` instead of `z == 4`  and `x == 2` shouldn't I?

Comment: How do I stay on type if I have vectors of separate classes (`factor`, `numeric`, `integer`, `character`)?

Comment: @lord.garbage No, because that check if the objects are the same. Consider `w <- 1:3; identical(w, 2)` which yield false.

Comment: @lord.garbage I guess you should just use `character`s or whatever type is necessary. But I guess you used letters in `y` and numerics in `x` to make your example more clear.

Comment: Ahhh, now I get your point. It would be fine to assign e.g. `1` but `a` forces it to become a character vector. Yes, true I did that in my example to illustrate my problem. Sorry, my original code does stay in   type!